# Error while accessing Web UI Dashboard using RBAC

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I created a cluster role "try-usr"

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: try-usr
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

While accessing the Web UI(Dashboard), it's throwing an error as follows:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services \"https:kubernetes-dashboard:\" is forbidden: User \"xyz\" cannot get services/proxy in the namespace \"kube-system\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "https:kubernetes-dashboard:",
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

Comment: Did you create a clusterrolebinding to bind your cluster role to the xyz user?

Comment: Yes I created. 
" kubectl create clusterrolebinding xyz --clusterrole="try-usr" --user=xyz ".
Sorry I haven't mentioned this.

Comment: Please, update the question with the output of `kubectl describe clusterrolebinding xyz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the kubernetes version, [the dashboard will require different permissions according to the docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Access-control#default-dashboard-privileges)

**v1.7**

- create and watch permissions for secrets in kube-system namespace required to - create and watch for changes of kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder secret.
- get, update and delete permissions for secrets named kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder and kubernetes-dashboard-certs in kube-system namespace.
- proxy permission to heapster service in kube-system namespace required to allow getting metrics from heapster.

**v1.8**

- create permission for secrets in kube-system namespace required to create kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder secret.
- get, update and delete permissions for secrets named kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder and kubernetes-dashboard-certs in kube-system namespace.
- get and update permissions for config map named kubernetes-dashboard-settings in kube-system namespace.
- proxy permission to heapster service in kube-system namespace required to allow getting metrics from heapster.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer when you can! Thanks!!